# Compute mean across intervals of rows

Tags: r

I have a long matrix, of which I need to compute the mean for a certain interval of rows. At the moment I am doing this manually like this:

```
values <- cbind(1:50,1)

meanqual10 <- mean(values[1:10,1])
meanqual10
[1] 5.5
meanqual15 <- mean(values[11:20,1])
meanqual15
[1] 15.5
meanqual20 <- mean(values[21:30,1])
meanqual20
[1] 25.5
meanqual25 <- mean(values[31:40,1])
meanqual25
[1] 35.5
meanqual30 <- mean(values[41:50,1])
meanqual30
[1] 45.5
```

There must be a nicer way of doing this. Can anybody help please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
by(values[,1], ceiling(1:50 / 10), mean)
```

`ceiling(1:50/10)` creates a vector of length 50 with a new integer every 10 numbers.

`by` will then take the `mean` for each group of the same integer.

Result:

```
ceiling(1:50/10): 1
[1] 5.5
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
ceiling(1:50/10): 2
[1] 15.5
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
ceiling(1:50/10): 3
[1] 25.5
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
ceiling(1:50/10): 4
[1] 35.5
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
ceiling(1:50/10): 5
[1] 45.5
```

Comment: very nice, I didn't know about ceiling yet. I am still new to R

Answer (score 5):

Señor O's answer is nice if you have regular intervals. Another approach, if you want to select arbitrary rows could be something like:

```
l <- list(1:10,11:20,21:30,31:40,41:50) # vectors of any length or ordering
sapply(l, function(x) mean(values[x,1]))
```

Which gives:

```
[1]  5.5 15.5 25.5 35.5 45.5
```

And of course `by` can do this for arbitrary rows, too. This is just a slightly different approach.